# Emoji crossword

Tags: crosswords, emoji

As part of celebration for reaching a score of 1000, I have decided to start making puzzles from now on. Now, I know this is not a very hard puzzle. I will start off making some simple puzzles, then gradually (hopefully) learn to make complex ones. With this in mind, I would really love for the newbies to have a chance to solve this. I remember scouting this site for a soluble yet unanswered puzzle for week or more before I found a chance to answer one.

**TLDR**
I would like to keep this puzzle open for newbies (1-100 rep) for a while before other experienced puzzlers can answer this. I will not say others should not/cannot answer, I only request those with higher reps to please wait for a while before answering. But I will gladly welcome any suggestions/improvements from everyone. Thank you :)

Now for the puzzle itself. For my first puzzle, I have created a crossword for which the clues are in the form of Whatsapp emojis.

[image: Crossword Grid]
[image: Clues]

NOTE:
Thanks to many of the higher rep folks who I know would have loved to answer but didn't. We had many new folks answering and I loved that! :D
I have accepted @prog_SAHIL's answer as he was the first to get all words right. But I would definitely encourage anyone looking to upvote his answer to also upvote other's answers along with his! Great job everyone :)

Comment: Since newcomers that already have an account on another SE site usually start with 100 rep ([association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/348535)), you should widen your newbie restriction to 0-200 rep.

Comment: Agree with @xhienne. That said, I think this is a nice idea.

Comment: Although I have been a member of the Puzzling Stack Exchange for several months, I have been mostly active for only about a month or so. That being said, what does TLDR mean? (Also, nice puzzle, though. I can't upvote because I have reached my daily voting limit and can vote again in $14$, so I favourited instead.) $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: Too Long Don’t Read

Comment: @user477343 [TLDR](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209439/what-does-tldr-mean-and-how-is-it-used) (or TL;DR) stands for "too long; didn't read" and is usually used to indicate a summary of a wall of text.

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails read my comment above :)

Comment: @xhienne, thanks for that! I had forgotten about the association bonus. I will definitely keep it in mind next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved,

> 3 Across - **LIQUOR** (Credits to Stefanto)
>  
>  4 Across - **NEURONS**
>  
>  6 Across - **FARM**
>  
>  7 Across - **SKIN**
>  
>  1 Down - **ASLEEP**
>  
>  2 Down - **POLAR** 
>  
>  5 Down - **SPORTS**
>  
>  6 Down - **FUNCTION**

Some artwork,

> [image: Crossword]

Comment: All right, just need to get 6 Down!

Comment: @nikki, Can you check now?

Comment: It's great to read then answer (I dont "work" on weekends ;-) but I cannot fond any reason why 6 down is FUNCTION

Comment: @Stefanto Function refers to a "gathering".

Answer (score 7):

I think that

> Across 5 is sports
>  Across 6 is farm
>  Across 4 is neurons   (Again Stephanto)
>  Across 3 is liquor    (Thanks to Stephanto)
>  Down 2 is polar       (Also thanks to Stephanto)
>  Down 1 is snores      (More Stephanto)

Comment: 5 down has 6 letters

Comment: Oh sorry, I was looking at 4 across

Comment: How would the 'V' fit in 7 across?

Comment: You have 6 of them correct! I had something else in mind for Down 1, but I can accept yours. Down 1 is a little off :/

Comment: What I had in mind was actually rot 13(nfyrrc), but I was willing to accept anything related to it as there was only one letter linked to the rest of the crossword.

Comment: Please make sure to use rot 13 to encode your answers when commenting. But apart from that, great answer, you have my +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

This is my attempt, but I hardly believe it is correct:

1. > **BEAUTY**. *Beauty* sleep.
2. > **ENDED**. Bears hibernate during the winter, and when they do, their typical lives would have *ended* for the time being.
3. > **DRINKS**.
4. > **STUDIES**. *Studies* about the brain, for instance.
5. > **SPORTS**.
6. > **PARTYING** (ACROSS) and **PETS** / **PEST** (ACROSS, and going with the latter).
7. > This is the stuff-up. My closest is <s>**INTUIT**</s> **SUIT**, as the senses *suit* everyone (?); they are highly convenient. I could also come up with **SH**$\ast$$\ast$, but that is not very appropriate.

Here is the entire crossword:

> [image: CROSSWORD] 
>  (Added an effect because I think it looks cool.)

---

## New Answer

> 2. (DOWN) = **RADAR** since when bears hibernate, they can become off the **radar** for a while.

> Based on what the OP commented below, I think 1. (DOWN) = **ASLEEP**.

> The OP also mentioned that **SPORTS** was correct, but that was the only one correct, so leaving that there, I think 4. (ACROSS) = **NEURONS**. (However, I find that the Puzzling Stack Exchange does not consider that a word, at least for me that is...)

> Assuming 6. (ACROSS) = **FARM**, I think 6. (DOWN) = <s>**FAVORITE** because the emojis could be dancing to their **favorite** song(s) or style of music? They seem to really be enjoying themselves!</s> one of the following four words. (I have included four and not picked one to not risk constantly editing my answer, which is also in a comment below.)

- > **FIGURINE** — the dancing emojis could be action figures (?);
- > **FINALIST** — the emojis could represent dance finalists in a show/audition;
- > **FEASTING** — the emojis might be dancing for a feast of some kind; or
- > **FIREBIRD** — there is an actual dance called the [*Firebird*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Firebird) by Stavinsky which the lady emoji might be dancing to!

> For the remaining words left, I have kept 3. (ACROSS) the same because I can't think of another word that fits... but I think 7. (ACROSS) = **SKIN**. That is my best bet. It might not be correct, but it is better than **SUIT**.

---

## Final Answer:

Oh, finally! I think I got it *this* time. (If I haven't, then I will look at the other answers, including the accepted one, because I haven't done that either!) I have included what I got correct in my new answer and what I did not. The comment section below this answer shows how I got up to this stage. [To OP:] Please make more of these crosswords (emoji or not)! :D

1. > **ASLEEP**.
2. > **POLAR** (thanks to the hint below).
3. > **LIQUOR** (thanks to the hint below, but how did I not think of this?).
4. > **NEURONS**.
5. > **SPORTS**.
6. > **FARM** (ACROSS) and **FUNCTION** (DOWN) (thanks to the hint below... otherwise, I would've killed myself trying to uncover this word).
7. > **SKIN** (thank God this word contains only $4$ letters).

Comment: That’s cool how you completed it, but I think some stuff is a bit off, like pest is probably farm

Comment: @RohitJose Yeah, you're right. I must admit, though, I did take a look at your answer, so I tried to solve the crossword without using any of the words you used (except for 3); and besides, if some of the words I used is a bit off, then I guess I haven't *really* completed it, have I? :P

Comment: You can use my answer is you want, and just credit me, but also it’s still amazing how you completed the crossword with actual words though

Comment: You only got 5 Down right. You arrived at the answer for 1 Down and then overshot it! But cool effect! :P

Comment: @nikki thanks! I will probably try again at this crossword later on today. It was really fun; I really enjoyed it. As a matter of fact, could 1 Down be Rot13(nfyrrc)? (Copy-and-paste the illegible/unreadable message into the upper box of [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/) to reveal a secret hidden message in the lower box!) If true, then 4 across could be Rot13(arhebaf)? :D

Comment: @nikki Adding to that, could 2 Down be Rot13(enqne)? Since $\ast$ (ROT13) ornef orpbzr "bss gur enqne" jura gurl uvoreangr. $\ast$ And taking into consideration of what **Rohit Jose** commented above, if I replace 6 across with Rot13(snez), could 6 down be Rot13(snibevgr)? Since $\ast$ (ROT13) gur rzbwvf pna or qnapvat gb gurve snibevgr fbat(f). $\ast$ However, I am Australian, and that is American spelling :P

Comment: You are right about 1 Down. But not about 2 Down or 6 Down. I tried my best to avoid words that have different spellings across countries :P

Comment: Okay, @nikki, I've found four words for 6 Down: $\ast$ (ROT13) SVTHEVAR (orpnhfr gur qnapvat rzbwvf pbhyq or npgvba svtherf?); SVANYVFG (gurl pbhyq or qnapr svanyvfgf va n fubj/nhqvgvba); SRNFGVAT (gur rzbwvf zvtug or qnapvat nobhg n srnfg); be SVEROVEQ (gurer vf na npghny qnapr pnyyrq gur sveroveq ol Fgnivafxl juvpu gur ynql rzbwv zvtug or qnapvat gb). $\ast$ It has to be one of them... and one last question: am I on the right track of thought for 2 Down, or not? (I hope this is my last before I finally solve this cross-word... I am resisting the temptation of looking at the other answers...)

Comment: I'll give you a hint for 6 Down: Gur jbeq vf nyfb hfrq va cebtenzzvat. And for 2 Down: Gur svefg rzbwv vf na nqwrpgvir sbe gur frpbaq bar. Just take the clue literally for 2 Down, it's very simple, I feel you're looking very deeply into it

Comment: @nikki Oh, how did I not notice before. The word for 6 Down must be Rot13(shapgvba)! (Also, (ROT13) gur jbeq vf hfrq va zngu(f).) For 2 Down, I thought of Rot13(fabj orne, pbzvat sebz gur jbeq "fabjsynxr" nsgre gnxvat gur pyhr n yvggyr zber yvgrenyyl.) That must mean the word is Rot13(cbyne), and then *that* means 3 Across *must* be Rot13(yvdhbe)! Ah, I think it is complete. I assume the other words are correct because you didn't mention anything about them. (At least I got 7 Across correct, in that case; that was probably the only one I got without any help using, I guess, "common sense".) :D

Comment: Yup! I think you got it right! I'm really glad that you actually tried to figure them all out by yourself even after an answer was accepted! :) I was saving my upvote for when you finished it and now you have it!

Comment: @nikki thank you! Hah, I guess hard work *does* pay off :P

Answer (score 4):

may i suggest the following

> 6  down : FEASTING (is that proper English ??) as it looks like it is all about a FEAST

Next try is

> 7 across : SKIN, as it is what could be missing to have a complete face

and I also would keep

> 6 across : FARM

I would change

> 3 across : LIQUOR

and then add

> 2 down : POLAR

I could keep

> 5 down : SPORTS eventhough there are too many ladies shown...

But it doesnt fit with

> 1 down : SNORES
>  4 across : NEURONE

So i try

> 5 down : (sporting) EVENTS

Comment: You've got most of them right! Keep what you could keep and look at @prog_SAHIL's answer for 4 Across! Just need to get 6 Down!

Comment: I see that a lot of people referenced your answers, great work! You have my +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Another (and now revised) attempt, with some different thoughts than others so far:

3 across:

> LIQUOR    (not drinks, as it has to start with L - see 2 down)

4 across:

> NEURONS (borrowed from other answers)

6 across:

> FARM

7 across:

> SKIN  (borrowed from other answers)

1 down:

> ASLEEP  (has to fit ????E?, others have guessed SNORES and SLEEPER.  I want to add ASLEEP)

2 down:

> POLAR  (snow bear?  What else could it be)

5 down:

> SPORTS

6 down:

> FLOURISH  (I knew this had to fit the pattern F????I?? based on other items.  This is just a guess right now.)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Great answer, most of your answers are right! Only 6 Down needs to be corrected :)

Comment: Here's a +1 from me!

Comment: Ok, well it's almost definitely not flautist, flourine, frosting, fraction, frontier, fidelity, or any of the hundreds of words Google tells me fit the pattern.  I'll keep trying.

Comment: Hmmm.... How about either ROT13(SERAMVRF or SERAMVRQ) ?

Comment: Nope, sorry :/ You were so close, but @prog_SAHIL got all answers right first. Please look at his answer. But great job for your first time! :)

Comment: I looked at that and dismissed it.  /shrug/.  Thanks for the fun diversion and the +1.

Answer (score 1):

7 across:

> HAND - body part used to touch

6 down:

> FLAMENCO - guess from the female's dress and dancing/party

Comment: Perhaps in your case, 5. could be Rot13(DHRAPU) since sport may prove to be tiring, and might make you drink in order to Rot13(DHRAPU lbhe guvefg)? :P

Comment: 4 across can't end in Q @user477343

Comment: That's what I first thought, but I didn't doubt the English language... until now :\

Comment: Nope, sorry, neither of them is right :/